# Read text using XML

Tags: xml, object, get

I have an issue with this code.I am tring to read the text file from a .txt doc using XML Http Object request.The code runs but nothing happen,the content of the div changes(the button disappear) but not with my file from the .txt doc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;

  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "text.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: What language? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: html,javascript ajax

Comment: the .txt file must be on a server ?I have it in the same folder with .html page